# best practice: native table or inserted figure

Tags: tables, best-practices

I have a relatively small table of data I would like to insert into my thesis. Is it better to natively create a table, or to externally create the figure and insert it?

Comment: This is a matter  of opinion, but you must know there are packages which can make a LaTeX table from a .csv file, among which `csvsimple` and `datatool`.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the table it is impossible to say. You could ask the same about a paragraph of text, whether to typeset it with tex or typeset it in something else and include as an image. On the face of it, if you have chosen to typeset the document in tex, using tex for typesetting seems the natural choice unless there are constraints that you have not mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A table of LaTeX code is only a chunk of text that could be placed inside the main document or in an external file, at convenience, but as an image could be only a heavier file (JPG, PNG), placed externally, may be of medium (PNG), low (JPG) or good quality (PDF) but anyway you cannot edit the table directly, so should maintain also the source-s file to create that table (spreadsheets, etc.). Let'see: At least 3 files instead of only one for a small document with a single table. If the document have, said, 20 tables, the source files might be up to 41 editable/non editable files (surely many Mb) instead of a single file of ridiculous size.

Another issue is the quality of the table itself. Using images will be difficult match consistently the font sizes, font styles, interline spacing, spaces above/below the table, etc., with the rest of the document.

Finally, make tables in LaTeX need some learning, but then make/edit  elegant tables is easy. When you know enough, edit a table in a WYSIWYG word processor is pain.  If that is not enough, you can import data from external sources in several ways (as cited by Bernard, `csvsimple`, `datatool`, but also exist `excel2latex`, `exceltex`, `odsfile` ...) not to mention R/knitr for the automatic generation of LaTeX tables.

These aspects are not a matter of opinion, but it is how important are for everyone and the weight of the circumstances. It could be understood use a screenshot of a table taken from a web page, for instance, in case of emergency (experts),  ignorance (novices) or impatience  (bunglers), but for me (me and my circumstances) there are no doubt: never ever.

Comment: +1! What does ìt mean "blungers"?

Comment: @CarLaTeX It means I have dyslexia `:(`

Comment: That's why the meaning of what I found in the dictionary seemed very strange in this context! Hahaha!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Why srtagne? Aaoccdrnig to a rsecheearr at an Elingsh uinervtisy, it deosn't mttaer in waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoetnt tihng is that frist and lsat ltteer is at the rghit pclae. The rset can be a toatl mses and you can sitll raed it wouthit a porbelm. Tihs is bcuseae we do not raed ervey lteter by itslef but the wrod as a wlohe. `:)`

Comment: @CarLaTeX Isn't it obvious?  Blungers are those who blungle their typing.

Comment: @Fran Do you spend your nights awake wondering if there is a dog?

Comment: @Fran Indeed, I have understood everything you have just written, and I'm not native English speaker, incredible!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, agnostic and insomniac  too.  `:)`